# Extend Symfony2 Controller

Tags: symfony

This works fine as a normal controller:

```
namespace BundleName\Bundle\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array("abc" => "test"));

    }

}
```

...so surely by doing this it should simply extend the controller:

```
namespace BundleName\Bundle\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ControllerExtension extends Controller
{
    public function render(string $view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {

        return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);

    }

}

class DefaultController extends ControllerExtension
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array("abc" => "test"));

    }

}
```

..but I get this error:

Runtime Notice: Declaration of ...ControllerExtension::render() should be compatible with that of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::render() in ...Bundle/SiteBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

Adding this makes no difference (which is a fix I saw somewhere):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
```

Comment: I fail to see why the overriden `render` method is easier to use than the previous one?

Comment: I fail to see why he had to override it at all ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is a lazy-type language. You cannot typehint strings, integers or booleans, only arrays and classnames.

So, in order to get a working function and correct PHP, you should do this:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; //! important as @Inori said

class ControllerExtension extends Controller
{
    public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Response` not `Request` :)

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Also, is it possible for the extension part to run for 'every' controller. Obviously I need to take it out of the controller file. I've tried calling it as a service, but can't get it working. I don't think including it in every controller is a good idea.

Comment: @user2143356 if you're using PHP 5.4 then you can define it as a trait

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on a late version of 5.3 and have no option to upgrade. Is there not a way to ensure every controller gets extended like this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` should be the fix, as currently you're actually trying to match `BundleName\Bundle\SiteBundle\Controller\Response` in `ControllerExtension::render`.

Where exactly are you adding the line?

P.S. I recommend you only define 1 class per file

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work though. I have tried it again just now (added it under the other use statements). The two classes in the file thing is just for demo purposes. There must be a solution to this - it should be simple.